# "Application configuration file "app.config" is invalid

Tags: c#, localdb

So I'm currently doing something from a book called "Headfirst C# 2nd Edition" and have had a number of problems seeing as its somewhat outdated. One of such problems is the error message in visual Studio 2019 when building a web app
"Application configuration file "app.config" is invalid. Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not closed: configuration. Line 6. position 1"
My code looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Thanks!

Comment: For web projects you should be using a web.config file.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/aspnet/create-web-config

Comment: Also, if you're going to use VS2019 you should probably just not bother with that book (that edition anyway).  MS Docs and the Internet are going to be more beneficial to you with updated information.

Comment: Thank you @squillman Just out of curiosity, where do you recommend I start with C#?